# Replacing only certain comments in xml using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

> I am trying to un-comment second authentication element. But while un-commenting '</authentication> -->' it replaces all '</authentication> -->' elements. We want only second element to be uncommented.

```
### Webconfig.xml ###
<webApi.webServer dateTimeZoneHandling="Local">
<!-- <authentication authenticationType="Windows" sessionTimeout="00:10:00" /> -->
<!-- <authentication authenticationType="Token" sessionTimeout="00:10:00" refreshTokenTimeout="99:00:00">
<tokenValidation validAudiences="e6b0f93b60250" securitykey="YmFzZT" validIssuers="WebApi"/>
</authentication> -->
```

> Token_replace.ps1

```
    $web_service_config_path= [IO.Path]::Combine("D:\Scripts\Powershell","Web_Sample.config")
    $xml =  (Get-Content $web_service_config_path)
    $start_tag = $false
    $end_tag = $false
    foreach ($line in $xml) {  
        Write-Host $line
        $r = $line -match '^\s*<!--\s*<authentication authenticationType="Token"\s*sessionTimeout="00:10:00"\w*'
        Write-Host $r
        if($line -match '^\s*<!--\s*<authentication authenticationType="Token"\s*sessionTimeout="00:10:00"\w*' )
        {
            if($start_tag -eq $false)
            {
                $xml = $xml -replace '^\s*<!--\s*<authentication authenticationType="Token"\s*sessionTimeout="00:10:00"',  '<authentication authenticationType="Token" sessionTimeout="00:30:00"'
                $pattern = '</authentication>\s*-->'
            $start_tag = $true
            }      
        }
        if($line -match $pattern -and $start_tag -eq $true)
        {
            $xml = $xml -replace '</authentication>\s*-->', '</authentication>'
            $end_tag = $true
        }
        if($start_tag -eq $true -and $end_tag -eq $true)
        {
            break
        }
    }
    $xml|Out-File -FilePath "D:\Scripts\Powershell\Web_new.config"
```

Comment: You want to uncomment the second `<!-- <authentication authenticationType="Token"` but also uncomment the next appearance of `</authentication> -->` or just uncomment the second one and that's it?

Comment: i want to uncomment the next appearance of </authentication> --> as well... Basically the entire second authentication block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried following block of code and it is working for me. I read a file line by line and same time added the line in another file. and replaced the line with comment before appending it to another. finallly deleted the original file and renamed new file with original file name.

```
        $web_service_config_path= [IO.Path]::Combine("D:\Scripts\Powershell","Web.config")
    $xml =  (Get-Content $web_service_config_path)
    
    if(Test-Path ".\Web_new.config")
    {
        Remove-Item -Path ".\Web_new.config" -Force 
    }
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path ".\Web_new.config" -Force
    $start_tag = $false
    $end_tag = $false
    foreach ($line in $xml) 
    {  
        if($line -match '^\s*<!--\s*<authentication authenticationType="Token"\s*sessionTimeout="\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"\w*' )
        {
            $line = $line -replace '^\s*<!--\s*<authentication authenticationType="Token"\s*sessionTimeout="\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"',  '<authentication authenticationType="Token" sessionTimeout="00:40:00"'
            $start_tag = $true
                  
        }
        if($line -match '</authentication>\s*-->' -and $start_tag -eq $true -and $end_tag -eq $false)
        {
            $line = $line -replace '\s*</authentication>\s*-->', '</authentication>'
            $end_tag = $true
        }
        $line | Add-Content -Path ".\Web_new.config"
        if($start_tag -eq $true -and $end_tag -eq $true)
        {
            continue 
        }

       
    }
  
Remove-Item -Path ".\Web.config" -Force
Move-Item "Web_new.config" "Web.config" -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this is XML, you shouldn't use string replacements on it like that.

To remove **ALL** comments in xml, use an [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0) object to load the file and have that set to ignore the comments. Then re-save the file to remove the comments.

```
$web_service_config_path = [IO.Path]::Combine("D:\Scripts\Powershell","Web_Sample.config")

# create a XmlReaderSettings object and have it ignore comments 
$settings = [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings]::new()
$settings.IgnoreComments = $true
# create a XmlReader object pointing to your config file and using the XmlReaderSettings
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($web_service_config_path, $settings)
# now load the config file in a new XmlDocument object using the XmlReader
$xmlDocument = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
$xmlDocument.Load($reader)
# dispose of the reader, otherwise the file cannot be overwritten
$reader.Dispose()
# and re-save the file
$xmlDocument.Save($web_service_config_path)
```

If you **selectively** want to remove the commented tags `<authentication .../>` you can do this:

```
$web_service_config_path = [IO.Path]::Combine("D:\Scripts\Powershell","Web_Sample.config")
# load the xml file
$xmlDocument = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
$xmlDocument.Load($web_service_config_path)
# select 'authentication' comments and remove them
$xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(.,'authentication')]") | ForEach-Object {
    $null = $_.ParentNode.removechild($_)
}
$xml.Save($web_service_config_path)
```

<sup>The first parameter of the `contains()` XPath function is used to specify the source node or string against which the comparison is to be executed. The second parameter is a string that specifies the word or string value to look for in the source node.
Remember that the `contains()` function is case-sensitive.</sup>